# How to average values over a period of time with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have been polling one integer counter for a week with 1min interval, but I added a new value to log file only if the value had changed. Initial value of this counter was 0 and at the moment the value is 111440. Log file can be seen [here](http://perl.nopaste.dk/p61757). Now if I tried to plot this data with gnuplot in a way that y-axe holds the value of the integer and x-axe holds the value of the time in minutes, then I obviously end up with a graph like this:

[image]

I should have stored each value even if it's the same as the previous one. At the moment I have only 3279 values stored while I have polled the counter 10080 times.

However, is there a possibility to "stretch" or average those results over a period of 10080 minutes with gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have lost some statistical information by not including all the data points, but you can stretch the data like this

```
plot 'data.dat' u ($0*10080.0/3279.0):1
```

to fill the space.

Gnuplot can do averages (version 4.6.0 and up):

```
stats 'data.dat'
help stats
```

Comment: For the data file @Martin showed, it should be `using ($0*(10080/3279.0)):1`.

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch.  I had read the first column in the pastebin link as a counter in the file, not the line number counter.

Comment: @andyras and @Christoph: what are the `$0*` and `:1` in `using ($0*(10080/3279.0)):1` datafile modifier?

Comment: @Martin `$1` refers to the first column and is a shorthand for `column(1)`, `$0` refers to the row index. The `$` sign is necessary only, if you do calculations inside the `using` statement: To select column 1 vs. 3, use `using 1:3`, if you need e.g. to stretch column `1` by a factor of `2`, you do it with `using ($1*2):3`.